# Asp Controls Does Not exsists in the Current Context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been renaming some classes and packages in my aspx project and now i have this error:

> "Type '_Default' already defines a member called 'Page_Load' with the
>   same parameter types"

I have two aspx pages. In the default.aspx codebehind i see:

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //error line under 'Page_Load'
    }
```

search.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="search.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

search.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    }
```

Now,what i tried here while Finding Sollution to  this Problem is to Access the other Partial Class Part and Removed the Defination of Page Load Method from there.
Steps that I followed are:

- **1-Renamed Errored Page load Method Temporarily.
- 2-In the Body Typed    Default and pressed F12. Now after this
  attempt,my that error is    disappeared but all My Controls Like
  textboxes etc appears not to be    in the current Context.Please Help
  me in this Regard.ThankYou.**

Comment: The class in search.aspx.cs should be named `_Search` by convention.

Answer (score 0):

You should rename the class of the "search" page to its name:

```
public partial class Search : System.Web.UI.Page
```

And the declaration obviously needs to be updated:

```
<%@ ... Inherits="Search" %>
```

Otherwise you have conflicting types.

Answer (score 0):

Your partial class definition in search.aspx should be changed to
`public partial class _Search : System.Web.UI.Page`

It's giving you that error because the method is being defined in two different pages at the same time

Comment: No need for an underscore for a non-special word.

Comment: You're right my apologies force of habit from typing as I look at the definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at code behind of the two pages, they are actually "extending" with the [partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wa80x488.aspx) keyword the `_Default` class and they are defining the `Page_Load` method two times.

In the search.aspx code behind you should instead declare the `search` class:

```
public partial class search: System.Web.UI.Page
{
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {...}
}
```